# Linking CSS with HTML ..something simple

Tags: html, css

I'm using a Mac and using textedit to create a website the old fashion way.  I have a HTML file and a CSS file.  I cannot link the CSS with the HTML. Here is the code for my files:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
       <link rel=“stylesheet” href=“style.css” type="text/css" media="screen">

       <title>William’s Physics Webpage</title>
   </head>

   <body>

     <div class = “nav”>
       <div class = “container”>
         <ul>
           <li> About Me </li>
           <li> Why Physics? </li>
           <li> Great Thinkers </li>
           <li> Guest Page </li>
         </ul>
       </div>
     </div>

   </body>

</html>
```

Here is my CSS code:

```
body {
    background-color:blue;
}

.nav ul {
   display:inline;
}
```

As you can see, the back ground is supposed to be blue due to the CSS code, but it's not.  The file name for my html file is main.html while the name of my css file is style.css

Comment: Please help me link the css code to my html code.  Thank you.

Comment: Your CSS file must be called style.css and it must also be in the same directory as the html file in question.

Comment: The double quotes you are using is not right `“ NOT THIS ”` . Use `" THIS IS RIGHT "`

Comment: Wait, Deepak, I don't understand what you just said.  Can you clarify?

Answer (score 3):

use proper " for style linking they are wrong "

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
```

Answer (score 0):

If both of the files are in the same file directory, your code should work, unless you are trying to run it online.

Make sure to put the correct path to the file.

Answer (score 0):

Look like  `media="screen"` gives me some error, try `media="print"` or not use media at all like this:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
```

Or the problem is that you used “ instead of " because you copied from somewhere and it pasted wrong. Try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the file path .. If your **html** and **css** file reside at same level means it should work fine.. or else if you have placed the **css** file inside **css** folder or some folder means..  your code would be like this

```
 <head>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="flodername/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
</head>
```